# ETL dataflow task - remain calculation

Tags: sql-server, etl, theory, dataflow

let me ask your help for understanding the main logic of data flow task. I'm using ETL to load data into data warehouse (staging and dwh part too). Now I got a task to calculate data with the existing fields, but have to calculate by inventory data...

[image]

I would need the correct qty of remain_qty, Assigned_qty and in_progress_qty. (as in picture). but currently I don't see this result. It would be great to get it.
I did the calculation process after the lookup get the list of inventory data.

[image]

Then check the actual temp data an other lookup. when it is not exist on temp by item, then insert the record, else just a simple update.. With this method I  would do the calculation process.. I think on the next record system should re-query the temp table and query the actual data.. I mean with the quantity reduced. record by record. But now it looks after this two lookup I got the same result for every row. that means for me the temp table does not re-query inside of the data flow. Shall I use an other data flow for calculation? Or may I use the temp table inside of this dataflow, which may updated by records? Because I would re-query the actual inventory quantity by records..
[image]
..Thanks for reading!

Comment: Please reformat your question to better explain, including screenshots, what you are trying to achieve, what you have tried so far and why it isn't working.  It is currently impossible to understand what you are trying to ask here...

Comment: sorry, you are right. I updated my questions. thank you for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Click here for picture!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oV8rv.jpg)
Hello guys, I have found a solution and made changes on the ETL process.. I have separated the data flow task and used stored procedure to re-calculate the data on temp table. Then the next data flow is able to query the updated data from temp and fill the fact table with correct quantity and price. That time I have learn the control flow and data flow processes. Now it is clear for me and the app is working fine. Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0):

I got confussed, but from what I understood you want to re-query using the Lookup Transformation, is that correct? If so, in the Lookup Transformation Editor, inside 'General' tab, there is the option for **Cache Mode**, by default, its marked as Full Cache.

1. **Full Cache** means that before doing anything inside the Data Flow
   Task, the database is queried once and saved in memory. So when you
   try to use Lookup Transformation inside the Data Flow Task, it will
   only use the Data saved in memory.
2. The second option is **Partial Cache**, queries some data before doing
   a transformation, and if its not found in there, queries the
   database again to find it.
3. At last, there is the **No Cache** Mode, where you query the
   database every single time a row is processed

You can find more detailed information [in this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattm/2008/10/18/lookup-cache-modes/).

Hope it helps

Comment: thank you for your solution. I have tried it, but does not solve my problem. Could you please take a look on the part of my project which may have the problem on the data flow? see pic3 above.

Comment: so, I have found the below article: [link](http://dbadiaries.com/t-sql-determine-the-difference-in-values-between-columns-in-different-rows)  what do you think, is it the only possible way to implement calculation of remain quantity? with CTE? :) maybe I could use variable arrays if possible.. I mean more item with its actual quantity.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the logic you have in the image. Although I'm not an expert in SSIS, it seems fine to me. Maybe you are using a package variable of some sort, saving and using the new value inside the Data Flow Task? the variables are not updated ntill the end of the Data flow task. That could be one reason. You can also separate them in 2 Data flows like you said and find out whats the problem in that way